# Animate transparency of part of mask with CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a view with `.brown` `backgroundColor`.

In that view I have a `backgroundView`, which has `backgroundColor: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)`.

I then want to have a transparent box in this `backgroundView` which shows the underlaying view. And I have achieved that, but I can't do it by animating its transparency, my code only grows the "cut out area" until desired size instead of animating it's transparency.

Brown view with the backgroundView and it's 0.5 alpha

[image: Brown view with the backgroundView and it's 0.5 alpha]

Added layer to backgroundView shows part of the brown view

[image: Added layer to backgroundView shows part of the brown view]

The code I've written to get what I have now is this:

```
func addIndicatorTo(global frame: CGRect) {
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    let targetRect = convert(frame, from: nil).insetBy(dx: -4, dy: -4)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")

    let toPath = CGMutablePath()
    toPath.addRect(bounds)
    toPath.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect,
                                byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).cgPath)
    toPath.closeSubpath()

    let fromPath = CGMutablePath()
    fromPath.addRect(bounds)
    fromPath.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect.insetBy(dx: targetRect.width / 2,
                                                                  dy: targetRect.height / 2),
                                  byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                                  cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).cgPath)
    fromPath.closeSubpath()

    animation.fromValue = fromPath
    animation.toValue = toPath
    animation.duration = 0.5

    shape.fillRule = .evenOdd
    shape.path = animation.fromValue as! CGPath

    backgroundView.layer.mask = shape
    shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    shape.path = toPath
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a "good" solution. But I will go with this until someone tells shows me how to solve it more elegantly!

Basically I just create a mask with the box cut out, then I create a new `boxLayer` with draws in the area of the "cutout". Then I just animate the `opacity` of the `boxLayer`.

```
func addIndicatorTo(global frame: CGRect) {
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let boxLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let targetRect = convert(frame, from: nil).insetBy(dx: -4, dy: -4)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")

    let toPath = CGMutablePath()

    let boxPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: targetRect,
                               byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                               cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).cgPath
    toPath.addRect(bounds)
    toPath.addPath(boxPath)
    toPath.closeSubpath()

    boxLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
    boxLayer.path = boxPath

    animation.fromValue = 1.0
    animation.toValue = 0.0
    animation.duration = 0.5

    maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
    maskLayer.path = toPath

    backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    layer.addSublayer(boxLayer)
    boxLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    boxLayer.opacity = 0.0
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```